# How to re-render a ReactJs component and refetch a query with Apollo when a state passed as props from a parent is updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client, use-state

There is a state `userIsAuthenticated` in my parent `App` component which is `false` by default but becomes `true` with the `setUserIsAuthenticated()` function when the user is logged in.

Now, in another component, I would like to display some user's data such as the username.
The user data is fetched from the backend API with Apollo:

Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

import { ME } from "../../api/authentication/me";

import LogoutButton from "../authentication/authentication-required/logout-button";


const Nav = ({ userIsAuthenticated }) => {
  const { data, loading, errors } = useQuery(ME);

  if (loading) return "User is loading...";
  if (errors) console.log(errors);

  return (
    <div className="Nav">
      {/* internalState = { internalState } */}
      <br />
      { JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) }
      <br />
      <LogoutButton/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is my problem: When the user logs in, the query is performed again but the component is not refreshed. This only works if I go on another page (I'm using `react-router-dom`) or if I refresh the page.

I know that in React, a state must change in the component or in its children in order to be rendered again, so I tried using update states in it which change when the received props `userIsAuthenticated` changes.

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
const Nav = ({ userIsAuthenticated }) => {
  const { data, loading, errors, refetch } = useQuery(ME);


  const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState(userIsAuthenticated);
  const [perviousValue, setPerviousValue] = useState();


  if (userIsAuthenticated !== perviousValue){
    const refetchMe = async() => {
      await setTimeout(() => await refetch();
    }
    refetchMe();
    setInternalState(userIsAuthenticated);
    setPerviousValue(userIsAuthenticated);
  }

  console.log(internalState);  // To check if the state is correctly updated


  if (loading) return "User is loading...";
  if (errors) console.log(errors);

  return (
    <div className="Nav">
      {/* internalState = { internalState } */}
      <br />
      { JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) }
      <br />
      <LogoutButton/>
    </div>
  )
```

But this doesn't solve the issue. The component is still not rerendered as long as I don't refresh the page or if I don't go to another page.

I also tried with the `useEffect` hook but I always end up in an infinite loop dispite only putting my `userIsAuthenticated` props in the dependency array.

Is there a way to rerender the component after refetching the query without having to refresh the page or moving to another one?

Comment: `useEffect(() => { /* code here */ }, [userIsAuthenticated]);`

Comment: I already made several tries with the `useEffect` hook but I always end up in an infinite loop where my component keeps rerendering. I updated my questions for more details.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the original problem is that the child components of <App /> aren't re-rendered when the auth state changes. However if that auth state is passed down as prop to the components, they will re-render. So you are trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. Ditch the internal state so the useEffect hook from my first comment uses the *prop*. This will re-run the useEffect function when the prop passed down from App changes.

Comment: Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js